# Hide or disable for edit properties in DevExtreme Scheduler and another questions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

I have an working scheduler which works with json data coming from ajax call. The problems i seem to not be able to find in documentation are:

1. How can i "disable" start/end date and remove `Description` (for example) in the edit pop up so they wont be changeable/visible? I only want to edit the schedule name.
2. How can i make the scheduler 'focus' on a specific schedule coming from the db? I have a filter which returns only one schedule but if its not in the `current date` it won't show up and i have to navigate manually to the date where the schedule is to see it, is there an option for that? The only way i think i can achieve that is to get the date and set it to the `currentDate` property, but is that possible in some way?

Comment: can you provide code or pen or fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To customize the appointment form use the [onAppointmentFormCreated](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxScheduler/Configuration/#onAppointmentFormCreated) event. See this [demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Scheduler/CustomTemplates/jQuery/Light/), as well.

2) To navigate a scheduler to the particular date use the [currentDate](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxScheduler/Configuration/#currentDate) option. The sample below shows how to do it using the [onContentReady](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxScheduler/Configuration/#onContentReady) option:

```
$("#scheduler").dxScheduler({
    /*...*/
    // set default current date too old for demo
    currentDate: new Date(2010, 4, 18),
    onContentReady: function(e) {
        // get all loaded appointments
        var appointments = e.component.getDataSource().items();
        // navigate to the first appointment
        e.component.option("currentDate", new Date(appointments[0].startDate));
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wn6jqdfn/

Answer (score 0):

Example to change Scheduller Properties Dialog:

```
$("#scheduler").dxScheduler({
    dataSource: ...
    onAppointmentFormOpening(e) {
        var form = e.form;
        form.beginUpdate();

        form.option("colCountByScreen", { lg: 1, xs: 1 }); // form always in one column
        form.getEditor("repeat").option("value", true); // turn on Repeat
        form.itemOption("mainGroup.allDay", "visible", false); // hide AllDay
        form.itemOption("mainGroup.description", "disabled", true); // disable Description
        form.itemOption('mainGroup.Text', 'cssClass', 'MyCssClass'); // add custom css class to Text

        form.endUpdate();
   },
});
```